# Understanding em Units in CSS and what is abbreviation of em?

Tags: css

Having worked in the web design and development field , it’s taken me a while to break free from fixed-width, pixel-based designs. Although I’ve started doing responsive layouts, I’m still hooked on pixel units. While this might be fine for layout elements, I think for typography, the em unit should be the go-to unit.

What is abbreviation of em ?

Comment: much of times google refers this site only.you should know this @MR_Green

Comment: @user3386628: Googling "CSS em" gave some pretty good results though. Have you even tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *em* is a unit of measurement in the field of typography, equal to the currently specified point size. The name of em is related to M. Originally the unit was derived from the width of the capital “M” in the given typeface.